# OpenGL ES application and running native Java code

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am using vs2017 to create OpenGL ES 1 code. I want to execute Java code from native C++. I am trying to add my own java file to the project. I added it under resources `src/com/a/b/sourcejni.java`.

I am not sure of how to load and interface with the source class. `FindClass` failed. Also nowhere in the project can I found template generated java files to edit. I checked the manifest to contain necessary fields.

This is my C++ code:

```
 JavaVM* lJavaVM = User_Data.state->activity->vm;
 JNIEnv* lJNIEnv = User_Data.state->activity->env;

 JavaVMAttachArgs lJavaVMAttachArgs;
 lJavaVMAttachArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
 lJavaVMAttachArgs.name = "NativeThread";
 lJavaVMAttachArgs.group = NULL;

 jint lResult = lJavaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&lJNIEnv, &lJavaVMAttachArgs);
 if (lResult == JNI_ERR)
  return;
   -------------------down to here works--------------------

 jobject lNativeActivity = User_Data.state->activity->clazz;



             --------Problem is Here---------

 jclass ClassNativeActivity = lJNIEnv->GetObjectClass(User_Data.state->activity->clazz); //This works but does not load correct class OR
 jclass ClassNativeActivity = lJNIEnv->FindClass("com/a/b/Sourcejni"); //Failes!

 if(ClassNativeActivity == NULL ){
     lJavaVM->DetachCurrentThread();
     return;
 }

  -----------------get variables, call functions here

 lJavaVM->DetachCurrentThread();
```

My problem is that I can't instantiate my own java file I placed in `jni/com/a/b/sourcejni.java` file in resources. Java file looks like this:

```
package com.a.b;

public class sourcejni {

    private String  nativeSampleRate;

    sourcejni( ) {
        nativeSampleRate="test123";
    }
    public void setStringAgain(){
        nativeSampleRate="321tset";
    }

    /*
     * Loading our lib
     */
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("sourcejni");
    }
}
```

I feel like I described my problem in enough detail what I am not certain about is that I get this properly.

Is there even a way to run own java code?

Answer (score 0):

**FindClass** accepts the fully qualified class name as the argument. So, if your java class is `com.sourcejni.sourcejni.sourcejni`, then below line should be modified from

```
jclass ClassNativeActivity = lJNIEnv->FindClass("com/x/y/sourcejni"); //Failes!
```

to

```
jclass ClassNativeActivity = lJNIEnv->FindClass("com/sourcejni/sourcejni/sourcejni");
```

Note that your class name is `sourcejni` and your package name is `com.sourcejni.sourcejni`, so your fully qualified class name is `com/sourcejni/sourcejni/sourcejni`. Also, just for your information, Java class / interface name should capitalise the first character, i.e. `sourcejni` should be `Sourcejni` by Java convention.

Comment: I used the advice (capitalization)  but it did not help. I simplified java class not to use activity, see edit.